# Linq SQL to filter columns

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Here is my table structure, all column decimal:

table

```
id column1 column2 column3
1   11.00   11.12   11.12
2   5.00    4.95    0
3   7.00    7.05    0
4   6.00    6.05    6.06
5   9.00    9.05    8.5
```

If I query like this:

```
List<stuff> stuffs = db.table.Where(a => a.column1 > a.column3).ToList();
```

it returns line 2, 3 and 5.

However, I need to check if column3 is zero, then if need to check for column2

Like: 
column1 > if (column3 > 0) column3 else column2

From my table it should return only 2 and 5.

How Can I modfied this to achieve it:

```
List<stuff> stuffs = db.table.Where(a => a.column1 > (a.column3 == 0 ? a.column2 : true)).ToList();
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Just as you wrote in pseudocode; `a.column3 > 0 ? a.column3 : a.column2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incredibly close. Just replace `true` with `a.column3`:

```
List<stuff> stuffs =
    db.table.Where(a => a.column1 > (a.column3 == 0 ? a.column2 : a.column3)).ToList();
```

Comment: And I just checked, LINQtoSQL does convert this into  `WHERE [Column1] > ( CASE WHEN [Column3] = 0 THEN [Column2] ELSE [Column3] END )`